# How to go to anchor tag in scrollable div without having the whole browser jump down?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, page-jump

I'm building a simple glossary widget as part of a larger project for a client. The content of the glossary is enclosed within a scrollable div (overflow:auto). Each letter has an anchor tag associated with it (#a, #b, #c, etc). Above the scrollable div is a div which contains every letter of the alphabet. Clicking on one of these letters takes the user down to that letter's definitions in the scrollable div. This works, but an unintended side effect is that the entire window jumps down to the anchor, which is confusing and annoying to the user.

Here is the widget, stripped down a bit and with a bunch of `<br />`'s to let you see what I mean.

http://www.nitrohandsome.com/clients/topics/glossary-widget/

I had tried a few different javascript ideas I cobbled together from some Googling, but nothing was working, so i just got rid of everything but the actual go to anchor code (I'm a pretty big JS newbie). So right now, clicking on any of the letters executes this javascript function, with the anchor tag passed to it:

```
    function jumpToAnchor(myAnchor) {
   window.location = String(window.location).replace(/\#.*$/, "") + myAnchor;
  }
```

How can I pull this off so the overall window doesn't jump each time a link is clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tested your example on IE8, FF 3.5, and Safari 4 on Windows. My screen height is 900px. The only time I noticed a jump problem was when my browser was less than the height of your widget, and the widget got pushed off the screen. Is this the problem you are talking about?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are talking about. The blank page was throwing me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can try the [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin. Also, to edit just the *hash* portion or the URL, you can just do

```
function jumpToAnchor(myAnchor) {
   window.location.hash = myAnchor;
}
```

Comment: I looked into the scrollTo plugin, but had trouble making it work. However, that page linked to http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12, which worked like a charm once I substituted p's for divs. Thanks!

Comment: I had a little trouble with it the first time I used it too, but I'm glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IFrame instead of Div or create a specific function using ScrollBy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the ideas! It actually was originally an iframe, but it had the same problem. I'll look into scrollby, but can it only be passed numeric values? The client may want to add or delete terms in the future, so if the links were hardcoded to a certain y position, it'd run into some problems. Any thoughts?
Thanks again!